# Update SQL Server table using XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml

From my ASP.Net application I am generating XML and pass it as input data to stored procedure as below,

```
<Aprroval>
  <Approve>
    <is_nb_approved>false</is_nb_approved>
    <is_approved>true</is_approved>
    <is_submitted>true</is_submitted>
    <UserId>35</UserId>
    <ClientId>405</ClientId>
    <taskDate>2015-05-23T00:00:00</taskDate>
  </Approve>
  <Approve>
    <is_nb_approved>false</is_nb_approved>
    <is_approved>true</is_approved>
    <is_submitted>true</is_submitted>
    <UserId>35</UserId>
    <ClientId>405</ClientId>
    <taskDate>2015-05-24T00:00:00</taskDate>
  </Approve>
</Approval>
```

And below is my stored procedure,

```
create procedure UpdateTaskStatus(@XMLdata XML)
  AS

UPDATE [TT_TaskDetail] 
SET 
    is_approved=Row.t.value('(is_approved/text())[1]','bit'),
    is_nb_approved=Row.t.value('(is_nb_approved/text())[1]','bit'),
    is_submitted=Row.t.value('(is_submitted/text())[1]','bit')
FROM @XMLdata.nodes('/Aprroval/Aprrove') as Row(t)
WHERE user_id = Row.t.value('(UserId/text())[1]','int') 
  AND client_id = Row.t.value('(ClientId/text())[1]','int') 
  AND taskdate = Row.t.value('(taskDate/text())[1]','date')
```

But when I execute this stored procedure, I am getting return value as `0` and no record is getting updated. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you try just selecting from that xml?

Comment: Yes, not returning anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your xml:

First is nonmatching root tags.

Second, more important, you are quering `nodes('/Aprroval/Aprrove')`, but inner tag is `Approve` not `Aprrove`.

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66b08/3

Answer (score 1):

Your outer tags do not match.  Your opening tag says, "Aprroval" instead of "Approval".  Once I corrected that, I was able to select from the XML without issue.